# How to make a R function which has an argument in FASTA format

Tags: r, bioinformatics, fasta

Here is a code written by me. And i was trying to run this function with an argument in FASTA format, but it is not working with this. please help me to change something in a code by which it could easily calculate with argument with FASTA format

```
I= 131.1736 
L= 131.1736 
K= 146.1882 
M= 149.2124 
F= 165.19
T= 119.1197 
W= 204.2262 
V= 117.1469 
R= 174.2017 
H= 155.1552 
A= 89.0935
N= 132.1184 
D= 133.1032 
C= 121.159 
E= 147.1299 
Q= 146.1451 
G= 75.0669
P= 115.131
S= 105.093
Y= 181.1894


ref=c(I= 131.1736, L= 131.1736, K= 146.1882, M= 149.2124, F= 165.19, T= 119.1197, W= 204.2262, V= 117.1469, R= 174.2017, H= 155.1552, A= 89.0935, N= 132.1184, D= 133.1032, C= 121.159, E= 147.1299, Q= 146.1451, G= 75.0669, P= 115.131, S= 105.093, Y= 181.1894)

#function to calculate molecular weights of amino acids, could be used by using ("",ref=ref)

mw=function(compound)
{
    molecules=unlist(strsplit(compound,""))
    ans=sum(ref[molecules])-((nchar(compound)-1)*18)
    return(c("Molecular Weight:"=ans))
}
```

Comment: Typo: `return(c("Molecular Weight:"=ans))`, should be `return(c("Molecular Weight:=", ans))` ?

Comment: Have a look at paste0.

Comment: Try `paste("Molecular Weight: =", ans)`, and no need to use `return`.

Comment: How does your "FASTA" format looks like, what is the input for `mw` function.

Comment: @zx8754 The input would be mw("ILILILDQFL"). Every thing is fine with this code but it wont give answer if i directly copy the sequence from the NCBI site(sequence is same as my argument). As the sequence is in FASTA format. so please help me regarding this. Here is the quick example for this= >KZV13477.1 CDC15 [Saccharomyces cerevisiae]
MNSMADTDRVNLTPIQRASEKSVQYHLKQVIGRGSYGVVYKAINKHTDQVVAIKEVVYENDEELNDIMAE
ISLLKNLNHNNIVKYHGFIRKSYELYILLE

Answer (score 2):

Using data from linked [fasta](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/KZV13477.1?report=fasta) there are new lines `"\n"` that needs to be removed. Added a filter to remove **any** character that is not in the ***ref***.

```
# reference lookup
ref <- c(I = 131.1736, L = 131.1736, K = 146.1882, M = 149.2124, F = 165.19,
         T = 119.1197, W = 204.2262, V = 117.1469, R = 174.2017, H = 155.1552,
         A = 89.0935, N = 132.1184, D = 133.1032, C = 121.159, E = 147.1299,
         Q = 146.1451, G = 75.0669, P = 115.131, S = 105.093, Y = 181.1894)

mw <- function(compound){
  molecules <- unlist(strsplit(compound, ""))

  # keep only letters that appear in ref
  molecules <- molecules[ molecules %in% names(ref) ]

  ans <- sum(ref[molecules]) - ((nchar(compound)-1) * 18)
  #return
  paste("Molecular Weight: =", ans)
}

mw("ILK")
# [1] "Molecular Weight: = 372.5354"

mw("MNSMADTDRVNLTPIQRASEKSVQYHLKQVIGRGSYGVVYKAINKHTDQVVAIKEVVYENDEELNDIMAEISLLKNLNHNNIVKYHGFIRKSYELYILLE")
# [1] "Molecular Weight: = 11583.6644"

mw(c("ILL", "LKKS"))
# [1] "Molecular Weight: = 886.1638" "Molecular Weight: = 868.1638"

# this one has "new line \n" which will be dropped
mw("MN\nISLL")
# [1] "Molecular Weight: = 671.9446"
```

Comment: could you please try to copy and paste this sequence from the link https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/KZV13477.1?report=fasta

Comment: @MayankSinghRajput There are some newlines that needs to be removed. Updated the function, now should work, tested with fasta from your link.

Comment: It was so helpful. Thank you so much for this help

Comment: @MayankSinghRajput See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Could you please help me in another function regarding this as well as i need a little help in debugging that function. I have tried to make my own portparam tool same as Expasy. Hence the sub functions work fine individually but as a whole it does not work. please help me in debugging this

Comment: Sir, i am unable to upload my code because of its length please suggest me a way to do this

Comment: @MayankSinghRajput If you have a new question regarding "another function" post as a separate new question, avoid asking new questions in the comments. If my answer was useful [consider upvoting and/or accepting as answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).